# How do I use IdentityUserRoles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm new to Razorpages and wanted to include the roles of the users in IdentityUser (which I have overriden with ApplicationUser for a custom groupname). Therefore exists a table UserRoles, but I'm not able to connect UserRoles to IdentityUser.

This would act as a tiny usermanager to set a group (e.g. department) and assign roles.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApplicationUser[0].UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApplicationUser[0].Group)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApplicationUser[0].Role)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ApplicationUser)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Group.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Any help is appreciated - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my ASP.NET 5.0 Blazor Server project, with EF Core, I followed the guidelines in [Identity Model Customisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to initially create as custom ApplicationUser class, which enhirits from IdentityUser (I'm sure you did the same here).  In my case I also change the PK type to GUID.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>> Claims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>> Logins { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserToken<Guid>> Tokens { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

As with IdentityUser, I also had to create custom classes for IdentityRole:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
    {
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

...as well as IdentityUserRole classes:

```
 public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    }
```

And then update my ApplicationDBContext to reference the custom classes:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<
        ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid,
        IdentityUserClaim<Guid>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<Guid>,
        IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>, IdentityUserToken<Guid>>
    {
```

Finally, I had to register the custom database context class when adding the identity service (in my Blazor project, under startup.cs).

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This would solve your issue:

> I'm not able to connect UserRoles to IdentityUser.:

I am now able to handle relationships between users and their roles as I handle relationships with any of my other models (while also making use of UserManager and RoleManager). For example, to assign a user to a role with UserManager: `await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(ApplicationUserObject, "admin");`

Comment: Wow, this is one superb and detailed step-by-step solution! I already implemented it and it works like a charm. Thank you very much for the fast help and have good one.

Comment: @Lau - you can upvote good answers in addition to accepting.

Comment: TFYI - That is exactly what i wanted to do, but I didn't have my 15 reputation points yesterday